# Return empty string in decimal function in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I create a function to compare the price of my item. 
This is my function:

```
public static decimal ComparePrice(decimal Price, decimal WebsitePrice)
    {
        decimal ZERO_PRICE = 0.00000M;
        if(Price == ZERO_PRICE && WebsitePrice > ZERO_PRICE){
            return WebsitePrice;
        }else if(Price == ZERO_PRICE && WebsitePrice == ZERO_PRICE){
            return "";
        }else{
            return Price;
        }

    }
```

if the both(price and websiteprice) is equal 0.00, then it will return the empty string, I know it is not possible to return the string while the function is set to decimal type, but i have no idea what should I do about that. Anyone can help? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it makes sense in your application logic, you can use a Nullable type and use null instead of an empty string. Like :

```
public static decimal? ComparePrice(decimal Price, decimal WebsitePrice)
    {
        if(Price == decimal.Zero && WebsitePrice > decimal.Zero){
            return WebsitePrice;
        }else if(Price == decimal.Zero && WebsitePrice == decimal.Zero){
            return null;
        }else{
            return Price;
        }

    }
```

Or use Decimal.MinValue as suggested as a flag for invalid. (I like the null better, again, just if this is actually a valid value in your logic).

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you return simple 0.0
Of course when both values are 0.0 .. returning 0.0 make sense.

Comment: umm... If I return 0.0, then I have to test again in my view, if the return value = 0.0 , then display empty string. Because all the items should not display its price = 0.0.

Comment: consider using nullable types as suggested by anthony and Francisco.

Answer (score 2):

C# has had [nullable types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) for quite a while now, try defining your method like this and returning null for the case in question:

`public static decimal? ComparePrice(decimal Price, decimal WebsitePrice)`

Comment: +1 for using standard ways of implementing this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You could always return something like decimal.MinValue that would indicate they were both a zero price item.